# AWS Aurora Postgres 9.6 major version upgrade via slony?

Tags: postgresql-9.6, upgrade, aws-aurora

The official documentation states that the major in-place version upgrades are not possible.

> **Note**
>   Aurora PostgreSQL does not currently support in-place major version upgrades. To migrate a database from one major version to another you can use dump and load tools such as the PostgreSQL utilities [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)

<sup>***Reference:*** [Upgrading an Aurora PostgreSQL DB Cluster Engine Version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html) ()</sup>

Is there any possibility of using tools like Slony for aurora postgres major version upgrade?

I'm bit sceptical owing to the container based approach of fully managed aurora.

Comment: You can do an in-place upgrade using `pg_upgrade` - at least with standard Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The question is concerning aurora-postgres-9.6 not plain RDS postgres-9.6